# How Do I Bind a UIButton Property to Another Property?

Tags: objective-c, ios, binding, uibutton

UIButton eventually inherits from NSObject, and NSObject implements NSKeyValueBindingCreation Protocol.  So why can't I bind a UIButton's property to another class' property?

```
[myUIButton bind:@"enabled"
        toObject:myOtherObject
     withKeyPath:@"otherObjectBOOLProperty"
         options:nil];
```

This results in the warning

> 'UIButton' may not respond to '-bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:'

What I'm trying to do is bind the enabled state of my UIButton to myOtherObject.otherObjectBOOLProperty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not so, iOS' `NSObject` does ***not*** conform to the `NSKeyValueBindingCreation` protocol.

I would use straight-up [Key-Value Observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/) in your case.

See the [Adopted Protocols](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-62012) of `NSObject`.

Comment: Ugh, yeah, thanks.  That's what I get for having both the Mac OS and iOS docs searched at the same time.  So I suppose the right way to do this is through KVO directly?

Comment: @cygnl7 I will also note that `NSKeyValueBindingCreation` is an informal protocol, so it doesn't show up in OS X's `NSObject` "Adopted Protocols" section either.

Comment: The docs for NSKeyValueBindingCreation Protocol state, "This informal protocol is implemented by NSObject," which is what got me.  I didn't even notice I was looking at Mac OS docs...

Answer (score 1):

NSObject only conforms to NSObject protocol but you can use KVO to bind that:

[Key-Value Observing Programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Concepts/KVOBasics.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002252-BAJEAIEE), Specially read how to register a property to be observed and how to receive notifications ;)